# Mean Squared Error as quantifier of the Bias-Variance tradeoff

Tags: variance, estimators, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

I have acquired the impression that many of the people doing statistical work, will prefer a biased estimator $\hat b$ to an unbiased one $\hat \beta$, if the former has lower Mean Squared Error.
This appears to be a way to quantify the "bias-variance trade off" (excerpt from the CV tag of the same name):

> *...In predictive modeling, unbiased models can have higher variance, & thus be less accurate. Modelers may prefer some bias to maximize accuracy...*

...since, in order to have lower MSE, it means that the variance is not just lower, but lower below a specific threshold,

$$MSE(\hat b) < MSE(\hat \beta) \implies \text{Var}(\hat b) < \text{Var}(\hat \beta) - \text{Bias}^2(\hat b)$$

**My request is for an elaboration of the argument as to why MSE is a reasonable quantifier of the "bias-variance tradeoff", and related references hopefully.**

...or against, proposing some other measure.

I link here two threads, which provide arguments in favor of using MSE or more generally "squared differences" as "loss functions",

[Why is the squared difference so commonly used?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/132622/28746)

and one that I have also contributed,

[What makes mean square error so good?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274650/28746)

but I stress that I am mostly interested in whether there is some argument about why MSE is a good quantifier of the bias-variance trade off.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking of this in the wrong way. It isn't that MSE quantifies bias-variance tradeoff. It's that people care about MSE, and MSE can be expressed as in terms of bias and variance. Because of that, people are willing to accept a bit of bias in exchange for a large reduction in variance, since that reduces the quantity they care about (MSE).

Comment: That's a bit circular don't you think? _Why_ people care about MSE? As for the"large" reduction, it depends: if the bias is lower than unity, an estimator that had variance lower than the variance of the unbiased estimator minus the bias - not bias squared, would be even more preferable. So the question is: "If I am better in MSE terms, it means I have variance lower by at least the squared bias". Fine, ok. Why reducing the variance by an amount equal to squared bias is the criterion to go by?

Comment: It isn't circular. People care about MSE. Since MSE has the bias-variance decomposition, people can manipulate bias and variance to lower the MSE.

Comment: Again: why people care about MSE specifically?