# Adaptive estimator for processing a file

Tags: bayesian, estimation

I want to estimate as good as mathematically possible the necessary time ($t_n$) for processing a given input file.

The estimation should be a function of the current file size ($s_n$) and all the previous $(s_i, t_i)_{i=0\dots n-1}$ file size --- processing time pairs. The input files are of the same type.

Is it there a better estimate than my naive

$$\frac{s_n}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{t_i}{s_i}?$$

Comment: "Better" in what sense, precisely?  "As good as mathematically possible" sounds nice but it's too vague to be of any use.  The answer also depends on the statistical characteristics of the data or your statistical model for them.  Note, though, that unless your previous file sizes were all fairly similar, your expression can be strongly affected by a single slightly unusual timing for a tiny file, which is not a good characteristic for most estimators.

Comment: @whuber: could you please summarise what would be your approach if you were given this programming task? This post describes one of my real-life coding tasks and my initial approach.

Comment: "Better" means that the difference between the estimated time (calculated prior processing the file) and the actual time (calculated after processing the file) is minimal.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a single definite difference: there will be many of them and they will follow some distribution.  You need to tell us how to make tradeoffs among those differences.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132622 for some of the concepts.

Comment: A simple $\left(\overline{t_n}-t_n\right)^2$ would do, I recon.

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense.  If by "$\overline t_n$" you mean the expectation of a random variable $t_n,$ then you likely mean to take the *expectation* of that squared difference.  In that case you are formulating a standard ordinary least squares prediction problem and the theory of OLS gives you an optimal estimator from that perspective.