# Show that if $E\psi(x-\theta)= 0 $ then $P(X< \theta) \leq p \leq P(X \leq \theta)$

Tags: probability, expected-value, convergence, estimators

Define $$\psi(x)=\begin{cases} 1-p & x < 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ -p & x> 0 \end{cases}$$. I have to show that if 
$$E\psi(x-\theta)= 0 $$ then $$P(X< \theta) \leq p \leq P(X \leq \theta)$$.

Any hints will be appreciated. What I have done so far is to state

$$E\psi(x-\theta)= \int_{-\infty}^\theta{(1-p)f(x)dx} - p \int_\theta^{\infty} {f(x)dx} = 0$$

Then what I get is that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\theta{(1-p)f(x)dx} =  p \int_\theta^{\infty} {f(x)dx}$$

But this doesn't help much

Comment: Are you sure there aren't typographical errors in your definition of $\psi$?  After all, except at $x=0$ your definition implies $\psi(x) \ge \min(p, 1-p) \gt 0,$ whence (assuming $0 \lt p\lt 1$ and $X$ is not just a constant), $$E(\psi(X-\theta)) \ge \min(p,1-p)(1-\Pr(X=\theta)) \gt 0,$$ whence it is never the case that $E(\psi(X-\theta))=0.$ One way to ensure the result would be to set $\psi=p$ for positive values and $\psi=p-1$ for negative values, as illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102986/percentile-loss-functions/103007#103007.

Comment: You are right, I had switched the two terms. Now it should be correct

Comment: That's better: now please fix the typographical errors in the remaining mathematical expressions!  That might get you most of the way to the finish.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the integrals as well. But I'm still lost. How should approach this?

Comment: Write down $\Pr(X\le \theta)$ and $\Pr(X\gt \theta)$ in terms of $f.$

Comment: Ok, I started going through your approach. Might work, I think. But could you explain how you got the expectations inequality?

Comment: Yes: $\psi$ is bounded below by $t=\min(p,1-p)$ everywhere except at $x=0.$  By the very definition of expectation (in terms of products of values and their probabilities), the expectation of this function is $t$ times the chance $X\ne 0$ plus $0$ times the chance $X=0.$  The latter term drops out and you can use $\Pr(X\ne 0)=1-\Pr(X=0).$  Applying this result to the random variable $X-\theta$ gives, with no more ado, $E(\psi(X-\theta))\ge(1-\Pr(X-\theta=0)).$

Comment: Do you mean in terms of $\psi(X)$? $f$ is just the density I assumed for $X$ - and going through it doesn't bring me further than what I have above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method assumes that $X$ is a continuous random variable, which is not stated as a condition of the problem.  It is possible to get the result in a more general case, so long as there is some non-zero probability that $X \neq \theta$.  From your stated form for $\psi$ you have:

$$\psi(X-\theta) = \mathbb{I}(X < \theta) - p \cdot \mathbb{I}(X \neq \theta).$$

Hence, taking the expected value you get the function:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mu(\theta) \equiv \mathbb{E}(\psi(X-\theta)) 
&= \mathbb{P}(X < \theta) - p \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \neq \theta). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Now, for the case where $\mathbb{P}(X \neq \theta)=0$ you have $\mu(\theta)=0$ for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$, so the implication you want to prove is not present in that case.  For the case where $\mathbb{P}(X \neq \theta)>0$ the expected value condition $\mu(\theta)=0$ implies that:

$$p = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X < \theta)}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)}.$$

With a bit of algebra you can obtain the required inequalities.  The first is established by:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X < \theta)}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)} \geqslant\mathbb{P}(X < \theta). 
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The second is established as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p 
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X < \theta)}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)} \\[6pt]
&\leqslant \frac{\mathbb{P}(X < \theta) + \mathbb{P}(X = \theta) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X > \theta)}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X < \theta) + \mathbb{P}(X = \theta) \cdot (1-\mathbb{P}(X < \theta)-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta))}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X < \theta) + \mathbb{P}(X = \theta) - \mathbb{P}(X = \theta)\mathbb{P}(X < \theta)-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)^2}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{(\mathbb{P}(X < \theta) + \mathbb{P}(X = \theta)) \cdot (1 - \mathbb{P}(X = \theta))}{1-\mathbb{P}(X = \theta)} \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X < \theta) + \mathbb{P}(X = \theta) \\[8pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant \theta). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify he first equation that you have above?

Comment: The symbol $\mathbb{I}$ is referring here to the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) which takes on a value of one if the argument statement is true, and a value of zero if it is false.  So you will see that this expression of the function is equivalent to your case-based expression.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. So, from the last equation I get that $P(X<\theta)<p$ but I can't get the $P(X \leq \theta)$. I try simply adding $P(X = 0)$ to get it after rearranging the equation on both sides but it doesn't help.. Any hints?

Comment: This part requires a bit of algebra.  Can you show that $b/(1-a) \leqslant b+a$ when $a+b \leqslant 1$?

Comment: No, I just can't get it...

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to approach this problem.

The point of the following is to take you through a process of analyzing the question, performing the requisite calculations as simply and easily as possible, developing a strategy to carry out the proof, and applying that strategy.  A section of concluding remarks highlights what has been achieved by this method.

#### Analysis

Recall that a [random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/54894#54894) $X$ assigns a number to each element $\omega$ of a sample space $\Omega.$

The expression $Y=\psi(X-\theta)$ is another way to assign numbers to elements of $\Omega;$ namely, for each $\omega,$ compute $\psi(X(\omega)-\theta).$

Notice that the resulting number is one of at most three values: $-p, 0,$ and $1-p.$  As you will see, we will be able to compute the probabilities of any subset of these values.
This makes $Y$ a random variable, too: and it's a *discrete* one.  This simplifies the calculations we might need to do.

At this point it is evident we need to accomplish two things: (1) we need to compute an expectation and (2) we will need to manipulate inequalities algebraically.  Let's take these in turn.

#### Preliminary calculations

The expectation of $Y$ can be found from the very definition: **multiply its values by its probabilities.**  Let's tabulate them:

1. For $X \lt \theta,$ $Y=\psi(X-\theta) = 1-p.$  This has probability $\Pr(X\lt \theta).$
2. For $X=\theta,$ $Y=\psi(0) = 0.$  This has probability $\Pr(X=\theta).$
3. For $X \gt \theta,$ $Y = -p.$  This has probability $\Pr(X \gt \theta).$

**The expectation of $Y$ is the sum of its values times their probabilities:**

$$\mathbb{E}(\psi(X-\theta)) = \mathbb{E}[Y] = (1-p)\Pr(X\lt\theta) + 0\Pr(X=\theta) + (-p)\Pr(X \gt \theta).\tag{1}$$

#### Strategy for the proof

The simplest way to carry out the required demonstration is to show its contrapositive: that is,

> if $\Pr(X \lt \theta)\gt p$ or $\Pr(X \le \theta) \lt p,$ we need to conclude that $\mathbb{E}(\psi(X-\theta))$ is *not* zero.

In the first case where $\Pr(X\lt \theta)\gt p,$ the [additivity of mutually exclusive events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) and the [axiom of unit measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Second_axiom)--two of the axioms of probability--guarantee that

$$\eqalign{
\Pr(X \gt \theta) &= 1 - (\Pr(X\lt\theta) + \Pr(X=\theta)) \\
&\le 1 - \Pr(X\lt \theta)\\
& \lt 1-p.
}$$

Substituting these two inequalities into $(1)$ gives

$$\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}(\psi(X-\theta)) &= (1-p)\Pr(X\lt\theta) -p\Pr(X \gt \theta) \\
&\gt (1-p)p - p(1-p) = 0,
}$$

proving the expectation cannot be zero.  The demonstration in the second case parallels this one, *QED.*

#### Comments

Because this proof is completely elementary--it relies only on the definition of expectation and axioms of probability--it reveals how little needs to be assumed and how general the result is:

1. It is not necessary to assume $0\lt p\lt 1:$ the assertion that was proved is true for all $p.$
2. This demonstration works even when $p=0$ or $1-p=0$ (whereas other attempts might fail for these values, in case they appear in the denominators of any fractions).
3. It was not necessary to assume $X$ has a density $f.$
4. No higher mathematical concepts, such as integration, were needed.
5. Indeed, we did not even have to use a distribution function for $X$: we worked directly with the relevant probabilities.

Comment: A good answer (+1), but I think there is presently an error.  In the case where $\mathbb{P}(X=\theta) = 1$ and $p>1$, the antecedent conditions for your theorem statement are met, but you get zero expectation.  I recommend actually going through the second case explicitly to deal with this.  (You actually need an exclusion on this case in the theorem.)

Comment: Thank you, @Ben, for taking such a close look.  That nicety does need to be addressed in the second case (which I have left to the reader) and evidently I was too glib in implying nothing goes wrong then. In the portion I have explicitly presented, because it is never the case that $\Pr(X\lt\theta) \gt p \gt 1,$ I don't see any problem. Perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: I think this is just a case where the OP needs to restate the result to rule out that special case.  That case is the only one that causes problems, so it is just a matter of ruling it out in the theorem.  In any case, I really like your approach to the proof (i.e., demonstrating the contrapositive).